# DynamoDb Nodejs - Put and Update table

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following table in `dynamoDB` that I want to write `value1` to on a first instance and leave `value2` blank. I then run extra code and only then do I want to update that item with `value2`.
I am new to `dynamodb` so am having some trouble with this.

How would I set-up my table so that the first write can contain only `value1` and the second write update the item with `value2`?

As it stands, I get the following error when trying to update:
`ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema`

I run the following script to create my `Id-map-table`:

```
var params3 = {
    TableName : "my-Id-map",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "value1", KeyType: "HASH" },
        { AttributeName: "value2", KeyType: "RANGE"}
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "value1", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "value2", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};

dynamodb.describeTable({TableName:"my-Id-map"}, function(err,result) {
     if (err) {
        createIdMapTable();
     }
   else {
        console.log("Table my-Id-map already exists");
    }
});

function createIdMapTable()
{
    dynamodb.createTable(params3, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        }
    });
}
```

I perform the first write in the following way:

```
itemManager.saveItemsId = function (value2, value1, callback) {

  value2 = value2.toString();
  value1 = value1.toString();

  var params = {
    TableName: 'my-Id-map',
    Item:{
      "value1": value1,
      "value2": value2
    }
  };

  dynamodb.put(params, callback);
};
```

I would like to `update` my item with something like:

```
    itemManager.updateItemId = function (value2, value1, callback) {
  value2 = value2.toString();
  value1 = value1.toString();

  var params = {
    TableName: 'my-Id-map',
    Key : {
      "value1" : {
        "S" : value1
      }
    },
    UpdateExpression : "SET #attrName =:attrValue",
    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
      "#attrName" : "value2"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
      ":attrValue" : {
        "S" : value2
      }
    }
  };

  dynamodb.update(params, callback);
};
```

Comment: Hi,with dynamoDB you cannt left value2 blank..since value2 is our RANGE KEY.its like primary key.So you cannot left value2 blank.

Comment: Ok. Say I just set it to 'Pending' and then update it? How would I write that?

Comment: what kind of error you are getting hyprstack,bcoz you are using WRONG SYNTAX for reating and updating table.

Comment: May i know that you are using the DynamoDB local or direct with AWS

Comment: I'm writing direct to AWS

Comment: Can i give you correct syntax

Comment: Write it in an answer so I can up-vote it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109262/discussion-between-arjun-kori-and-hyprstack).

Answer (score 5):

As i can see that your createTable() and describeTable() Syntax are right but update and insert commands are wrong.

In your insert command there should be putItems() and in update there should be updateItem.

Here i m giving you syntax.
This is Syntax for **putItem i.e insert command**

```
itemManager.saveItemsId = function(value2, value1, callback) {

value2 = value2.toString();
value1 = value1.toString();

var params = {
    TableName: 'my-Id-map',
    Item: {
        'value1': {
            'S': value1
        },
        'vallue2': {
            'S': value2
        }
    }
};
dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error")
    } else {
        console.log("Data saved Success")
    }
})
```

};

For **update** the table :

```
itemManager.updateItemId = function(value2, value1, callback) {

value2 = value2.toString();
value1 = value1.toString();

var params = {
    TableName: 'my-Id-map',
    Key: {
        id: {
            'S': id
        }
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET #attrName =:attrValue',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#attrName": "value2"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':attrValue': {
            'S': value2
        },
    }
};
dynamodb.updateItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error while update")

    } else {
        console.log("Data updated Successfully")
    }
})
```

};

Also you can refer this link [dynamodbSyntax](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html)

Comment: Why do they use 'put' in this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.03)?

Comment: that is for older version, look into the doc which i shred http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

Comment: when you are requiring the npm module verify the apiVersion

Comment: Sorry about that arjun. I should have mentioned I was using the [DocClient Class](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property)

Comment: ha ha no problem buddy! but my link helps you

Comment: Thanks for posting the syntax stuff .. I have to go pick up my eyeballs off the floor.  Does anyone mock this somehow specially when writing Node.  Find I'm just in a loop of failure.

Answer (score 3):

I have decided to answer my question.

It turns out that because I am creating a compound key (HASH + RANGE), I am trying to update the key itself and dynamodb complains about that. I need to change the way I create the table to have only a HASH key in order for the rest to work.

Creating the table should be:

```
var params3 = {
    TableName : "my-Id-map",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "value1", KeyType: "HASH" }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "value1", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};
```

So that writing an item:

```
itemManager.saveItemsId = function (value1, callback) {
  value1 = value1.toString();

  var params = {
    TableName: 'my-Id-map',
    Item:{
      "value1": value1
    }
  };

  dynamodb.put(params, callback);
};
```

and updating:

```
itemManager.updateItemId = function (value2, value1, callback) {
  value2 = value2.toString();
  value1 = value1.toString();

  var params = {
    TableName: 'my-Id-map',
    Key : {
      "value1" : value1
    },
    UpdateExpression : "SET #attrName =:attrValue",
    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
      "#attrName" : "value2"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
      ":attrValue" : value2
    }
  };

  dynamodb.update(params, callback);
};
```